Why is my razor view not sending the users input data to the action method?
I have created an application for an online book store. I have decided to use Firebase for the authentication and have now ran into an issue with the login and register view where both the views do not send any data to the method on the controller.
Here is the register view for reference:
@model BogusBooksStore.Models.LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h4>Register</h4>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Register">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Passw" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Passw" class="form-control" type="password" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Passw" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:30px;" formmethod="post"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Login">Already have an account? Login</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }

A snippet of the controller
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(LoginModel login)
        {
            try
            {
                await auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(login.Email, login.Passw);

                var fbAuthLink = await auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(login.Email, login.Passw);
                string currentUserId = fbAuthLink.User.LocalId;

                if (currentUserId != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("currentUser", currentUserId);
                    return RedirectToAction("Books", "Index");
                }
            }
            catch (FirebaseAuthException ex)
            {
                var firebaseEx = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FirebaseErrorModel>(ex.ResponseData);
                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, firebaseEx.error.message);
                return View(login);
            }

            return View();
        }

The relevant model:
namespace BogusBooksStore.Models
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
        public string Passw { get; set; } = null!;

        public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}


I tried using plain string instead of an object however i have gotten the same results.

mmm, don't know - that formmethod on the button looks a little suspect. I would check the html - make sure the method is post and the form is being submitted to the correct place. Checks in the browser - ensure that the form is being posted / values are there might help.

One thing that comes to my mind is the asp-controller tag missing from the form. Try adding that and see if it posts to the right controller's action.

What happens if you use @using (Html.BeginForm... instead?

Tried using Html.BeginForm and it made no difference.
It is calling the correct action but the values it gives it are Null.

You can set a breakpoint at   Register(LoginModel login) . I test your code and get the result like:  https://i.sstatic.net/1jsco.png
